# I cannot locate a download link by using Selenium in the drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn selenium and i am trying to download an excel file from a drop down menu.
Firstly, i click to button in order to open it and afterwards when i do inspect i am able to get to this part.

I am trying to click this part and download the file.

```
<span _ngcontent-bke-c150="" class="left-text">Excel</span>
```

[image]

Here is the link to the website: https://survey123.arcgis.com/

I don't think sharing my code would help because i am already stuck at that very specific part. I was able to login to the website through selenium and enter id and password but failed at downloading the excel file.

But here it is

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://survey123.arcgis.com/")



inputElement_user = driver.find_element_by_id("user_username")
inputElement_user.send_keys("myusername")
inputElement_password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password")
inputElement_password.send_keys("mypassword")
giris_button = driver.find_element_by_id("signIn")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(giris_button)
actions.perform()

continue_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Rapor')
```

Comment: can you provide a link to the web page?

Comment: where is your python code?

Comment: FYI, some site may had anti bot design

Comment: since we don't have login to the website, i suggest to click on the dropdown menu first and click on the "EXCEL" you want

Comment: @Prophet I provided the link but you need to be registered.

Comment: @Wonka I edited the post and put down my code

Comment: @chikabala I tried that one code works without any error but it does not click the menu.

Answer (score 0):

This might not exactly be the answer but I had also stuck on this point some time ago. I tried this `<a href="file/path/or/link/here" download>` and it worked.
the `download` property makes files downloadable, if the `href` is set properly. hope this works in your problem as well.